# JQuery select following div of each instance of a class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have several h1's with a div below them. Is there any way to select only the div right after the h1? The code I have right now slideToggles all of the div's with a clickable class.

JQuery

```
$(".clickable").click(function() {
    $(".clickable + div").slideToggle(1000);
});
```

HTML

```
<h1 class="clickable">HTML/CSS</h1>
<div class="hidden">
    <p>Here are my examples</p>
    <p>Here are my examples</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next) does all you want:

```
$(".clickable").click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(1000);
});
```

Comment: upvoting this because the others don't seem to know the inefficiency of (A) specifying any selectors if it is the very next object, and (B) having tag qualifiers to class selectors

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Yes, there's no need for the selector here if the next element is reliably the one you want. A `filter` call is inefficient. It's a pity we can't do `$(this.nextElementSibling)` yet...

Answer (score 1):

You need this -

```
$(".clickable").click(function() {
    $(this).next('div.hidden').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` to refer to the H1 you're clicking on. By using `$(".clickable + div")` within the click handler you refer to all divs that are children of any H1. By using $(this) within the event handler you refer just to the one clicked.

```
$(".clickable").click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(1000);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k9taL/3/)**

Comment: @AttitudeMonger - see the explanation in my answer.

Comment: Oh sorry sorry, didn't notice! :)